# Restart WPF Application

Tags: wpf, xbap

My application has many views and I am using an AutoLogoffHelper class which maintains the timer for the application. Due to inactivity if the timer is 0, it call the log off event (which is also in the AutoLogoffhelper class).

As of now I am using Application.shutdown to completely shutdown the Application.

But Is there a way to restart the application or delete navigation history and session information and navigate to login screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To restart you can use `Process.Start` and the command line args (which automatically contain the application's path):

```
Process.Start(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
```

Comment: Putting that in just prior to the `Application.Shutdown` call of course. =)